# i can't over come subquery return more than one row

Tags: mysql

Subquery returns more than 1 row.this problem is occurs during excecuting following query

```
    select 
         profileid
         ,(
              select profileid from customer where gender in
              (select gender from customer c where c.profileid= cc.profileid)
          )
    from customer cc where 
    profileid in(10000,10001)
```

i want to get list of customers they are in opposite gender if the selected person

Comment: Please express more clearly what you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single query you need to select the results on the outside.

Here, I've added your criteria as a subquery in the WHERE statement so that you have the gender of the targets.

Of course, if the ID numbers result in different genders, you'll get no results. I don't know if you're storing gender is an integer or a string. If it's a string you'll probably need to replace `NOT IN` for `<>`.

```
SELECT cc.profileid
FROM customer cc
WHERE cc.gender NOT IN (
    SELECT gender FROM customer WHERE profileid IN (10000,10001)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say following query

```
select gender from customer c where c.profileid= cc.profileid
```

outputs "**Male**"

Then this query

```
select profileid from customer where gender in ("Male")
```

will give out multiple columns.